# Display images from directory with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, .htaccess

i'm new to PHP and jQuery but i would like to do the following things to a portfolio that i'm developing using easySlider and Lightbox plugin:

1. Display a limit of six images or six div images per "li" tag and close it from a directory.

   - If there is more than six images on the directory, create a new "li" tag and show six more images, till all the images from that directory are loaded.
   - If an image has a name with a number after -> display: Hidden. For example: beta1 but i only want to show the first one "beta"
   - Sort images by name.
2. Don't let anyone access to the images on that directory, if it isn't the code itself.

The code for portfolio is the following:

```
<div id="portfolio_hold">
   <ul>

     <li>
      <div class="portfolio_pic_hold">

        <a href="large.jpg" rel="lightbox[]" >
          <img src="thumb.jpg"/>
        </a>

      </div>
     </li>

   </ul>
</div>
```

This is my html example of what i want to show.

Comment: Your question reads like a specification. Please edit it with details of the specific problem you're having, and what code you've written so far.

Comment: so write the code that does that. what are you asking us?

Comment: I didn't write any code so far so no problem at the moment thats why i asked this particular question because i don't have enough bases to do it.I asked this to get some help or lights to how to

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick

```
$thumbsPath = "trabalhos/design/thumbs/";
$imagespath = "trabalhos/design/images/";
$file_display = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');

if (file_exists($thumbsPath) == false)
{
    echo 'Directory \'', $thumbsPath, '\' not found.';
}
else
{
    $thumbs = glob($thumbsPath."*.[".implode($file_display,"|")."]");
    if (file_exists($imagesPath) == false){
            echo 'Directory \'', $imagesPath, '\' not found.';
    } else
    {
            $counter = 0;
            $filesPerPage = 6;
            foreach ($thumbs as $file)
            {
                    if($counter % $filesPerPage) echo "<li>";
                    $counter++;
                    $info = pathinfo($file);
                    $sFile =  basename($file,'.'.$info['extension']);

                    $aFiles = glob($images.$sFile."[0-9]+.[".implode($file_display,"|")."]"); //Este array tem todas as imagens relativas ao thumbnail que estás a ver
                    echo "<div><img /></div>";
                    if($counter == $filesPerPage) echo "</li>";
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here: http://pastebin.com/CvvJQAix, i reworked @Mind code because i don't know the reason why it wasn't showing the images / thumbnails but now this "rework" does it all. I got another problem now that it is the following: I limit the number of images per li but doesn't show other <li> tags beside the first one even if i can see the other images with lightbox, which disables my easySlider Plugin.